# is it secure to use SKIP_FLIGHT_CHECK=true and openssl-legacy-provider in react script npm start?

Tags: reactjs, node.js, security, npm, react-scripts

I am working on a react app which has old versions of most of the libraries being used in package.json file.

for e.g

```
"react": "^16.3.1",
"react-scripts": "^3.0.1"
...
```

While installing packages with the latest version of NodeJS (>18), I got conflict dependencies errors so I used `npm install --legacy-peer-deps`.

With that my installation was successful, but when I went to run using npm start, it started to give an error related to webpack version 4.42.2.

I did debug and found one solution and updated the script like below,

```
"start": "cross-env SKIP_FLIGHT_CHECK=true react-scripts --openssl-legacy-provider start"
```

With the above, it starts running fine.

Now I want to check with this solution are there any changes to the security breach?

Or is it secure in terms of any attacks?

Comment: `SKIP_FLIGHT_CHECK` is a yarn environment variable, you seem to be using npm, is this variable necessary?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it does increase the security risks on your app, there's no way to tell if it can cause major issues or not, but it's an additional risk.

As per [node documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#--openssl-legacy-provider), the flag `--openssl-legacy-provider` enables OpenSSL 3.0 legacy provider. [OpenSSL documentation](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man3.0/man7/OSSL_PROVIDER-legacy.html) states that:

> The OpenSSL legacy provider supplies OpenSSL implementations of algorithms that have been deemed legacy. Such algorithms have commonly fallen out of use, **have been deemed insecure by the cryptography community**, or something similar.

So to keep you app as secure as possible, you should avoid using the `--openssl-legacy-provider` flag.

Comment: Okay.. but is there any other way to handle this? Actually in my organisation they are using internal registry to maintain packages and they have quarantined few of the packages which are internal dependencies of packages like babel or webpack. So as of now if I want to keep the old versions of each package including node js and override the quarantined versions then is there any way to do?

Comment: I don't think there's another way around no. Having the latest version of each package does increase the security of your app since you'll get all the latest security patches. The risk of having older version of packages might be very slim, it might not justify the time investment into updating all of your packages. But again, to answer your initial question, yes it does increase the risk, it might be a small/negligible, but if you strive to reduce risks as much as possible, you should do all the updates you can.